# HttpResponseMessage parameters received after constructor is called

Tags: c#, asp.net, constructor

I have an API controller that when called from the client passes database credentials.

```
public class ForemanController : ApiController
{
    static SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder ();

    public ForemanController()
    {
       //database calls with connection string
    }

    public void Get(string DataSource, string InitialCatalog, string UserID, string Password)
    {
        connectionString.DataSource = DataSource;
        connectionString.InitialCatalog = InitialCatalog;
        connectionString.UserID = UserID;
        connectionString.Password = Password;
    }
}
```

The get method is working fine and I can see the credentials being passed via the client code:

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage resp = client.GetAsync("api/foreman?DataSource=dxdv&InitialCatalog=Q19410&UserID=tunld&Password=did").Result;
```

My problem is that the constructor in the ApiController runs before the get method so the database calls fail because of a null connection string.

How do I get the parameters to pass before the constructor?

Comment: What workflow do you have in mind? Do you want to initialize the connection string with get method and then use it for some other requests keeping connection in the instance of controller Get has been called for? Or do you want your Get to call database using connection string and return something?

Comment: I don't know a lot about API's, but if I'm reading this correctly, you're calling the constructor instead of the Get functiuon ('api/foreman' iso 'api/foreman/get' ). So either adjust your call or set parameters for the constructor

Comment: @Igor The former, I want to initialize the connection string and then do the requests.

Comment: @Devcon2 calling the get still makes constructor run 1st

Comment: You can initialize your database inside Get. Is there any reason to do it in constructor?

Comment: @Igor That will work! Thanks.

Comment: However if you don't store your database connection somewhere externally (cache, database, etc) you rely on web service being never restarted. And it scales awfully of cause.